# LockerService issue with Safari, Component not accessible in debugger

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning, aura, locker-service

Component:

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
```

Controller:

```
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

       console.log(component);
       debugger;
    },
```

Safari Debugger presents error on `component`, and when used for doing more complex functions, fails. This is present on desktop, iPhone and simulator Safari.

[image: Safari Debugger]

Comment: Does your code contain any uses of eval, or is safari dev tools injecting it?

Comment: Maybe the Safari dev tools are injecting it... I will try to find out.

Answer (score 2):

For any future readers.. this has been fixed a while ago in a patch and the Safari debugger should now log LockerService objects without errors.